# pom.xml Maven configuration to run JUnit 4 + JUnit 5 Jupiter tests in mixed Java + Kotlin project

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I cannot configure maven project successfully to run mixed JUnit 4 / JUnit 5 Jupiter tests for Java and Kotlin.

I have no problems to configure Gradle (for instance [this configuration works well](https://github.com/daggerok/kotlin-examples/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-examples/build.gradle.kts) for my needs), but not maven. I have tried different configurations of maven, Kotlin, surefire plugins with different versions of JUnit Jupiter and platform dependencies, but wasn't success...

Can anyone of you provide worked example?

I have also posted similar questions on JUnit team GitHub issues and in Kotlin slack channel:
 - https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1899
 - https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C0922A726/p155880442804330

---

Regards,
Maksim

Comment: You should configure Maven project to use JUnit Jupiter which can run (via vintage) JUnit 4 tests. (More or less the same as in Gradle).

Comment: Hey @khmarbaise, can you post here link to worked pom.xml example you are talking about? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay... I spent couple of hours and seems like I found answer. Here example of worked pom.xml file for multi-module maven project to execute mixed JUnit 4 Vintage and JUnit 5 Jupiter tests together with mixed Java and Kotlin test classes with limitations described like so:

```
src/
  test/
    java/
      **/*JUnit4VintageJavaTest.java  +
      **/*JUnit4VintageKotlinTest.kt  +
      **/*JUnit5JupiterJavaTest.java  +
      **/*JUnit5JupiterKotlinTest.kt  +
    kotlin/
      **/*JUnit4VintageJavaTest.java  -
      **/*JUnit4VintageKotlinTest.kt  +
      **/*JUnit5JupiterJavaTest.java  -
      **/*JUnit5JupiterKotlinTest.kt  +
```

where

`+` means: tests are going to be executed

`-` means: for some reasons test are not going to be executed with provided configuration...

*pom.xml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.github.daggerok</groupId>
  <artifactId>mixed-kotlin-java-jupiter-tests-maven-execution</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <!--
  <modules>
    <module>module-1</module>
    <module>module-2</module>
  </modules>
  -->

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.31</kotlin.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.5.0-M1</junit-jupiter.version>
    <junit-platform.version>1.5.0-M1</junit-platform.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- junit 4 -->
    <dependency><!-- already contains junit:4.12 dependency, so we are not going to add it explicitly! -->
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- vintage engine is required if you wanna execute JUnit 4 together with JUnit 5 Jupiter tests... -->
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- junit 5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <!-- includes junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0 and junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0, but we need other versions -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- includes junit-jupiter-api and junit-jupiter-engine dependencies -->
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <experimentalCoroutines>enable</experimentalCoroutines>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirs>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
              </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirs>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
              </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>java-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>java-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

worked example located [here](https://github.com/daggerok/mixed-kotlin-java-jupiter-tests)

*how to verify:*

```sh
git clone https://github.com/daggerok/mixed-kotlin-java-jupiter-tests testme ; cd $_ ; mvn test
```

Only question cannot answer if it's possible and how to configure maven project where allowed place and recognize java test classes in src/test/kotlin test sources directory? But seems like it's a different question and that one must be closed.

my PR with according sample was just merged to junit-team/junit5-samples project and available [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven-kotlin)

Comment: It's most likely that `*Test.java` tests in `kotlin` source directory are not executed, because they are not compiled in the first place, since maven java compiler plugin doesn't know it should look java sources in kotlin directory.

Comment: @Ilya, looks like so. question is: is it possible to properly configure maven to do what is needed? Gradle can successfully run tests for both languages from both directories...